# Why I cant observe the effect of 4/8-way set associative cache in my test code

Tags: c, optimization, caching, memory

I am trying to reproduce an experiment [described here](https://youtu.be/BP6NxVxDQIs?t=1480). The result should show the effect of 4/8-way set associative cache--when the step size is "just right", cache memory will be saturated easily, dragging down the performance a lot.

The below is my test code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  const size_t arr_len = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
  uint32_t* arr = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t) * arr_len);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_len; ++i) {
    arr[i] = rand();
  }
  struct timespec ts;
  uint8_t sum = 0;
  double delta, t0;
  size_t idx;
  for (size_t step = 1; step < 2049; ++step) {
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    t0 = ts.tv_sec + ts.tv_nsec / 1000.0 / 1000.0 / 1000.0;
    idx = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_len; ++i) {        
        arr[idx] += step;
        sum += arr[idx];
        idx = (idx + step) % arr_len;
    }
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    delta = ts.tv_sec + ts.tv_nsec / 1000.0 / 1000.0 / 1000.0 - t0;
    printf("%lu, %lf\n", step, delta);
  }

  free(arr);
  return sum;
}
```

It turns out that the performance of each iteration is pretty stable and I fail to observe the effect resulting from the k-way set associative cache. Is there something wrong with my code? (Just in case it is relevant, my CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v4)

Comment: You should check if malloc was successful or not. It's naive to assume that malloc will always succeed in allocating 1Gb of space for you.

Comment: Newer CPUs use a hash of the virtual address to compute the index of the cacheline. Maybe this is the reason why no cache alising is observed

Comment: @Lundin for the purpose of this test I dont think that is necessary--Linux always makes it clear by emitting a segment fault if memory allocation failed

Comment: @tstanisl you mean that we cant not easily predict which memory blocks share one set of cache, so that it will still appear random even if we access sequentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `step == 1` this code will touch 1 GiB of data, which won't fit in cache regardless of associativity, leading to a cache miss every 16 accesses where none of the cache misses have anything to do with associativity.

When `step == 16` this code will still touch 1 GiB of data, which won't fit in cache regardless of associativity, but will only use a cache line once (before its evicted) leading to a cache miss on every access where none of the cache misses have anything to do with associativity.

As `step` increases the number of cache misses that have nothing to do with associativity decreases, and the number of cache misses that are caused by (low) associativity increases.

Specifically; for `step == 2048` the values of `idx` would be `0, 2048, 4096, ..., 268433408, 0, 2048, 4096, ..., 268433408, 0, 2048, 4096, ..., 268433408` and the CPU would only need to touch 131072 cache lines or 8 MiB of data (and wouldn't touch the whole 1 GiB of data). Your CPU has 10 MiB cache, so (depending on "address swizzling", associativity and how close "pseudo LRU" is to "strict LRU") it's possible that all of the cache misses disappear.

Essentially; your array is too big (significantly larger than cache size) when `step` is low, so "cache misses that have nothing to do with associativity" are obscuring "cache misses that are a consequence of associativity"; and this ruins your results.

To fix/avoid that you want to ensure that the total amount of data touched is constant and doesn't exceed cache size. In other words, when `step == 16` you want to access every cache line in an 8 MiB array, when `step == 32` you want to access every second cache line in a 16 MiB array, when `step == 64` you want to access every 4th cache line in a 32 MiB array, etc.

For example (untested):

```
#define CACHE_SIZE       (8*1024*1024)   // MUST be a power of 2
#define CACHE_LINE_SIZE  64              // MUST be a power of 2
#define MAX_STEP         8192            // MUST be a power of 2
#define ACCESSES         123435

int main() {
    const size_t arr_len = (CACHE_SIZE / CACHE_LINE_SIZE) * MAX_STEP;
    uint8_t* arr;
    struct timespec ts;
    uint8_t sum = 0;
    double delta, t0;
    size_t idx;
    size_t test_size;
    size_t test_size_mask;

    arr = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * arr_len);   // Consider something like "mmap()" on Linux or "VirtualAlloc()" on Windows here
    if(arr == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (size_t step = CACHE_LINE_SIZE; step <= MAX_STEP; step *= 2) {

        test_size = (CACHE_SIZE / CACHE_LINE_SIZE) * step;
        test_size_mask = test_size - 1;

        timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
        t0 = ts.tv_sec + ts.tv_nsec / 1000.0 / 1000.0 / 1000.0;
        idx = 0;
        for(int accesses = 0; accesses < ACCESSES; accesses++) { 
            arr[idx] += step;
            sum += arr[idx];
            idx = (idx + step) & test_size_mask;
        }

        timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
        delta = ts.tv_sec + ts.tv_nsec / 1000.0 / 1000.0 / 1000.0 - t0;
        printf("%lu, %lf\n", step, delta);
    }
```

Also; depending on which OS it is; I'd want to try to use large/huge pages to minimize the chance that the translation of virtual addresses into physical addresses doesn't artificially reduce associativity (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coloring ).

Comment: Hi @Brendan, without quite understanding why your proposal will work, I implemented it [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c/01_memory-and-cpu-cache/07_cache-associativity/main.c). But the result appears to be the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: Merely reducing the array size won't keep the amount of data touched constant (because with step larger than cache line size you're not touching/skipping over some parts of the array). I added some example code to my answer to illustrate.

Comment: the rabbit goes deeper than I initially thought. Your code works as it is. But I notice that in your code, you use `idx = (idx + step) & test_size_mask;`. I believe it is equivalent to `idx = (idx + step) % test_size;`. However, if I switch it back to `idx = (idx + step) % test_size;`, the magic goes away. Still investigating the reason... The complete version of the code incorporating your modification can be found [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/ce816635b51e6028fa9e63ca58f78f48e591c74e/c/01_memory-and-cpu-cache/07_cache-associativity/main_new.c)

Comment: `idx = (idx + step) & test_size_mask;` doesnt really work though--`test_size` is a function of `step` and `step` has to be arbitrary to demonstrate what the experiment wants to show. This modification means `test_size` must be a power of 2, which deprives us of the opportunity to observe the results from the rest of the `step`s...

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: "Power of 2" is the magic. Assume we have a simple 4 MiB cache with 4-way associativity. With "step = 1 MiB" all accesses fight for the same 4 places in the cache and performance is very bad because most of the cache isn't being used. With "step = 1" or "step = 2" or "step = 0.99 MiB" or "step = 1.01 MiB" this doesn't happen so there's no performance difference and we can't observe the effect of associativity.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: More specifically; we want `(cache_size/cache_associativity) % step == 0`, and we assume `cache_size/cache_associativity` is a power of 2 (because it always is - e.g. for your CPU `cache_size/cache_associativity = 10 MiB / 20 = 512 KiB = pow(2, 19)`), so we can assume that if step is a power of 2 it will work for any cache.

Comment: the purpose of the original experiment is that, we want to compare the performance of different step sizes. The expected behavior is that, if step size is a power of 2, it should be much slower than step size that is not a power of 2. I incorporated your code to the benchmark. Source code is [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c/01_memory-and-cpu-cache/07_cache-associativity/main_new.c) and the result is [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c/01_memory-and-cpu-cache/07_cache-associativity/results_new.csv).

Comment: so you can see that we still **cant** observe the expected results from your version. Note that I made two significant changes to your code. 1. `++step` instead of `step *=2`, 2. `idx = (idx + step) % test_size;` instead of`idx = (idx + step) & test_size_mask;` (as step size is arbitrary now.)

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: There's multiple causes of interference - it's actually the effects of 3 different caches (L1, L2, L3) merged, things like code & stack also compete for cache, the CPU has hardware prefetchers and modulo is slow so part of the cost of fetching data is hidden by the modulo; and recent Intel CPUs (since 2008/Nehalem?) have done "swizzling" (location in the cache depends on a hash of the physical address and not the raw address) to mitigate cache timing attacks.  With all that in mind; those results (trending worse as step increases with large amount of "noise") aren't unexpected.

Comment: so my take is, as mentioned by @tstanisl in his comment, there is no straightforward way to observe cache associativity on an Intel CPU nowadays if we are allowed to use standard C only ("to use standard C only" means we don't call some kind of kernel driver to directly query the number of sets, etc). Do I get your point correctly?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: If you knew what the hash algorithm is you could compensate (find an erratic pattern that, after hashing, becomes sequential at the cache); and there's some research into reverse engineering the hash algorithms (see https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/690.pdf ). It's also technically possible (for privileged/kernel code) to disable hardware prefetching, and you could downlock RAM chips too, to increase the impact of cache misses. There's also a bunch of higher order stuff (TLB and TLB misses, RAM chip pages and banks, ..) that could possibly be avoided in theory.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: Mostly, it's possible, but extremely complicated. Note that if you just want to know the cache's characteristics (sizes, number of sets, associativity) you can get that information from the `CPUID` instruction.